# How to blend a texture with two color channels in opengl?

Tags: opengl

I'm using ray casting tech to rendering a texture.I just need a color channel like red, green or blue whatever,and an alpha channel to use `glBlendFunc` to blend the color channel as mentioned.But after checking internal formats of texture in opengl, I find no format like `GL_GA`,just have `GL_RG`. Must I use format like `GL_RGBA` and discard two color channels?

Comment: If you want two channels use `GL_RG`. You can always swizzle the texel components, have a look at [glTexParameter](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml) and the parameters `GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_[R|G|B|A|RGBA]`.